# Brand of kitchen sink with crown logo and CSA stamp

Tags: kitchen-sink

I'm looking for the brand/manufacturer of this stainless steel double kitchen sink with a crown logo both on the sink and the strainer, as well as a CSA stamp... In Canada as you can guess. Guessing this is a low-cost, contractor available sink, may have been sold via Home Hardware.

[image: Sink with crown logo, three rounded tips]

Answer (score 3):

OK, turns out a little bit more research never hurts. It was a Kindred sink: https://www.kindred-sinkware.com/ca/en.html

Comment: Canadian Tire carries this brand, and these sink strainers

Answer (score 1):

Have been researching this myself.  Steel Queen was the brand name at the time.  Moen, and Wessan and yes, Cdn. Tire carry versions of the strainer which I need.  I ordered Wessan from Home Depot online. Not sold in store. Look for #1000811009.  Wessan looks closer to my original than Moen which has thinner rubber piece.  Just found the PlumbShop one online.  It actually mentions Steel Queen.